# Is there any query to find the sum of quantity of child having the same name in Firebase Database(Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0

Query to find the sum of the quantity of item having the same name...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCPHU.png)

```
final Query query2 = billdata.orderByChild ( "name" );
        query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent ( new ValueEventListener ()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    int total1 = Integer.parseInt ( String.valueOf ( dataSnapshot1.child ( "qty" ).getValue () ) );
                    int sum=0;
                    sum=sum+total1;
                    Toast.makeText (this,"Whole Total"+sum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific query for calculating the sum of the child, you want to do like this

```
// declare an int variable in global like this  
             int globalsum=0;

    final Query query2 = billdata.orderByChild ( "name" );
            query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent ( new ValueEventListener ()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    int sum=0;
                    for ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        int total1 = Integer.parseInt ( String.valueOf ( dataSnapshot1.child ( "qty" ).getValue () ) );

                        sum=sum+total1;
                        globalsum=sum;
                        Toast.makeText (this,"Whole Total"+sum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();
```